# Convexity and concavity in a textbook figure of the fundamental solution of the heat equation $u_t - u_{xx} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis, mathematical-modeling

My textbook has this image of the fundamental solution of the heat equation $u_t - u_{xx} = 0$ for $0.25 \le t \le 10$:

[image]

It says that, when we deduce from the PDE that at locations where $u_{xx} < 0$ (so $u$ is convex in $x$) the solution decreases in time at fixed $x$ whereas, when $u_{xx} > 0$ (so $u$ is concave) the solution increases in time. The points of inflection, where $u_{xx}$ changes sign, separate regions where the solution is increasing in time from those where it is decreasing.

Convex vs. Concave:

[image]

Am I thinking about this incorrectly, or does this description not match the figure provided? For constant $x$ "beneath" the line (when $u$ is convex in $x$), we see that the solution decreases till about $t = 1$ and then actually increases. And, for constant $x$ "above" the line (when $u$ is concave in $x$), the solution actually decreases in time till about $t = 1$ and only then seems to increase.

Hmm, I'm not sure if I'm interpreting this incorrectly, or if this is an error by the author?

Comment: Kindly add the PDE also so that it is easy to determine whether the claims are true or false.

Comment: @MathLover Oops, sorry. I have added it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author has accidentally switched the words "concave" and "convex", but if you ignore those two words and read the maths(which is what I did originally), he is correct :)  Its nothing more than combining the PDE $u_t = u_{xx}$ with the fact that $u_t < 0$ means $u$ is decreasing (and similarly for increasing.)

I remember which way round things are by remembering that $x^2$ is convex, and $(x^2)'' > 0$.

I've also attempted to recreate the graph. Note the contour lines, showing the decrease in height at $x=0$.
[image]

Not quite the same, but hopefully this helps. From different angles-
[image][image]

Edit - I just found out that Geogebra has an online 3D grapher. It even has a mode for the oldschool red-blue 3D glasses. [I recreated the graph again here, and this time its interactive.](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/nvqsjp5u)

Comment: Silly me! Nice images. You are of course correct for the former. But for $u_{xx} > 0$ ($u$ concave in $x$), doesn't the solution for any fixed $x$ still decrease as $t$ increases? Fix $x = 0$ and we can see that as $t$ increases $u$ decreases?

Comment: @Wyuw  $u_{xx} > 0$ is /convex/. I remember it by remembering that $x^2$ is convex, and $(x^2)'' > 0$.

Comment: Those are the author's words when I said concave and convex. So it's the author that is wrong!? "when we deduce from the PDE that at locations where $u_{xx} < 0$ (so $u$ is convex in $x$) the solution decreases in time at fixed $x$ whereas, when $u_{xx} > 0$ (so $u$ is concave) the solution increases in time. The points of inflection, where $u_{xx}$ changes sign, separate regions where the solution is increasing in time from those where it is decreasing." I think we found the culprit of confusion?

Comment: Oh. Yes, the author has made a typo. I assumed he was correct because the pictures you gave in the OP classify $\pm (x-a)^2 + b$ correctly as convex/concave.

Comment: @Wyuw It is instructive to notice that if you define $\tau = -t$, ("reverse time") and let $w(x,\tau) = u(x,t)$, then $w$ solves the equation $w_{\tau} = -w_{xx}$. So you can see the effect of having the wrong sign in the same graph as well. Namely, there is finite time blowup of the solution instead of decay to 0.

Comment: Thanks! But what we discussed is an error by the author? I just want to make sure before I contact someone.

Comment: @Wyuw Yes. the diagrams at the bottom of your post are correct, the author's math symbols are correct, but he has switched the words "concave" and "convex". I will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: Ok thank you for this information.